# XamarinForms APK won't install - App not installed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

We have two apps which are deployed using HockeyApp (Ad Hoc deployment).
After recent updates on my Mac (iOS & Visual Studio Community) I can't install them on Android devices (deployment to iOS devices steill works fine).

I have a message "App not installed".
It is the same when I try to install from APK file on the device (signed or unsigned apk).
I can install the app on the phone in Release mode when I have it connected to the Mac.

I'm not sure what else I should check to investigate this issue?

Visual Studio Community version 7.6.1 (build 9)
iOS version 10.13.16
HockeyApp.SDK.Xamarin 5.1.2
Xamarin.Forms 3.1.0.697729

Comment: Check what your supported Architectures you have set for release https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/cpu-architectures?tabs=vswin

Comment: Architecture is set to armeabi-v7a. It was always like that and it worked before. Like I said I'm able to install the app on the phone when it's connected to the PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Visual Studio - 7.6 build 2190 creates invalid APK for Ad Hock or Android Play Store release.

Comment: Is it fixed now? because I have 7.6.1 and I am facing the same exact problem. On older android APIs and older phones it seems to work fine, but for new ones it can not be installed